# The default_ui_timezone as well as dag timezone - in airflow- both are not getting updated

Tags: timezone, airflow

I have set the default_ui_timezone as well as default_timezone in the airflow configuration overrides, as mentioned below and I could see this in the cfg file as well. but the UI is still showing the UTC and the dags are running in UTC.

webserver
default_ui_timezone
Europe/London

core
default_timezone
Europe/London

Is there anyway to change this to Local Europe/London Time ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you running it locally or with Docker? If so [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67218723/10569220) answer may help you.

Answer (score 0):

After changing the config, use the menu in the drop down located towards the top right of the screen and select the desired timezone. https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/timezone.html#web-ui has a screenshot of it.

Comment: hi,Its being run in cloud composer using Kubernetes cluster. I am not able to see the droip down in UI and alos could not find a way to get the dag time changed.

Comment: If its cloud composer, then this question is already answered in another stackoverflow thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67206938/i-want-to-change-the-timezone-of-the-airflow-webserver-created-by-cloud-composer

Comment: That didnt work, It changed in the CONFIGURATION OVERRIDES, but when I open the UI, it still shows the UTC time . Command executed : gcloud composer environments update test-001 \
  --location europe-west2 \
  --update-airflow-configs=webserver-default_ui_timezone=BST

Comment: @Mohammed did you get it work; i too don't see the override configuration changing anything.